# Where to put external jsoup file for Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio, jar, jsoup

I am trying to write an Android app using the jsoup external library. I can't get it to build! Every time I always get:

> com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lorg/jsoup/Connection$Base;
>   UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:

I have used the jsoup 1.7.1 successfully in eclipse. I tried using it with Studio for the first time. I modified the build.gradle file like so:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.1'
```

}

I also tried this with jsoup 1.8.3, and got the same results. I am not sure if I am putting the jar file in the correct place on my hard drive. I have put it in both %PROJECT%\libs\ and \AndroidStudio\lib\

Any ideas where to put it? Or am I doing something wrong in the build.grade? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.1'` tells gradle to download jsoup as a remote artifact from a repository.  The error you are getting is because you have jsoup included twice!  "Multiple dex files define" -> defined twice.  The solution is to delete the .jar file you have locally in your project.